# Interpolation in R with akima

Tags: r, interpolation, gregorian-calendar, julian-date

This is the first time I have used the package akima, and have run into some problems

[My try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmZTR.jpg)

I have made a interpolation plot in R with dates on the x-axis and depth on the y-axis. My dates are in julian, but I would like to have gregorian dates. So 01/01/2016 instead of 1.

```
attach(temp)
t <- interp(date,depth,temp,duplicate="mean")
filled.contour(t,col=matlab.like(18),xlab="Date",ylab="Depth (m)", main="Temperature")
```

Is it possible to increase the number of ticks at the x-axis?

Thanks for all help